How to prevent two separate web apps from sharing the same session state
I have 2 separate ASP.NET web apps, when I run them locally from Visual Studio or from a remote IIS server where they are deployed, they always use the same session state although I use separate application pools on the server.
Below are the details. What am I doing wrong in my code or configuration? When I use different browser for each application, it seems to work fine.
Web App 1
a) Authentication via login form
Response.Cookies.Add(New HttpCookie("ASP.NET_zebs-admin_SessionId", String.Empty)) 

If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Me.Request.QueryString("ReturnUrl")) Then
    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(UserEmail, False) 
Else
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(UserEmail, False)   
       Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.DefaultUrl, False)
End If

b) Session state in web.config
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="30" 
        regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" 
        cookieName="ASP.NET_zebs-admin_SessionId" />

Web App 2
a) Authentication via login form
Response.Cookies.Add(New HttpCookie("ASP.NET_Zebs_SessionId", String.Empty))

If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Me.Request.QueryString("ReturnUrl")) Then
    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(UserEmail, False)       
Else
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(UserEmail, False)        
    Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.DefaultUrl, False)
End If

B) Session state in web.config
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="30" 
        regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" 
        cookieName="ASP.NET_Zebs_SessionId"/>`

I want separate session state for each web app

I never set the cookie name, and always let iis generate that cooikeName. However, if you have 2 different sites, then why not give the 2nd site a different cookie name, and thus you should see/have 2 different sessions? To be fair, am somewhat surprised they both use the same in-proc session, but I would either remove the cookieName setting, or simply ensure that the 2nd site has a different cookieName set. So, it not really all that clear why you forcing and setting the cookie name - why not just let IIS choose and set that cookie name?

Thank for your feedback, i figured out a solution by renaming the defaut cookie name of FORMAUTH

In my experience, this can be caused by the same MachineKey in the Web.Config file of both instances of the application. Each instance of the site should have its own unique MachineKey.
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <machineKey validationKey="9F22CD0D3DC702FDB7B909820B13E3409B70EF452DA45A5C94EC7A4AE229F3F2FE3A713F78580E7F1719464EC2ED4107DC46DD3BDD5B9B4DA1EDC04CB0336441" decryptionKey="4FD2EAE1C815D7E4FD59F278494F1EFE2E40246E22CB6A04EB9565D7889FEACF" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>

Above is a sample MachineKey I generated randomly with the code below.
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace KeyGen
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Version arguments to MachineKey.Generate() method.
    /// </summary>
    public enum MachineKeyVersion
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// .NET version 1.1.
        /// </summary>
        Net1,

        /// <summary>
        /// .NET version 2.0 and up.
        /// </summary>
        Net2,
    }

    public class MachineKey
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Generates the contents of a machineKey element suitable for use in
        /// an ASP.NET web.config file.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="version">Indicates if keys should be generated for
        /// ASP.NET 1.1 or 2.0 and later.</param>
        public static string Generate(MachineKeyVersion version)
        {
            // Generate keys
            string validationKey = GenerateKey(64);
            string decryptionKey;
            if (version == MachineKeyVersion.Net1)
                decryptionKey = GenerateKey(24);
            else
                decryptionKey = GenerateKey(32);

            // Construct <machineKey> tag
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.Append("<machineKey");
            builder.AppendFormat(" validationKey=\"{0}\"", validationKey);
            builder.AppendFormat(" decryptionKey=\"{0}\"", decryptionKey);
            builder.Append(" validation=\"SHA1\"");
            if (version == MachineKeyVersion.Net2)
                builder.Append(" decryption=\"AES\"");
            builder.Append(" />");
            return builder.ToString();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Generates a string of random hex digits of the specified
        /// number of bytes.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="length">Number of bytes to generate</param>
        protected static string GenerateKey(int length)
        {
            RNGCryptoServiceProvider rngCsp = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] buff = new byte[length];
            rngCsp.GetBytes(buff);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(buff.Length * 2);
            for (int i = 0; i < buff.Length; i++)
                sb.Append(string.Format("{0:X2}", buff[i]));
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
}

